# List files with timestamp since epoch

Tags: bash, shell, find, xargs, stat

I basically want to combine the output of

```
find /
```

with the output of:

```
find / | xargs -L1 stat -c%Z
```

The first command lists the files in the / directory and the second lists the timestamp of each file. I want to combine these two such that I get the file and the timestamp on one like, like:

```
/path/to/file 1501834915
```

Comment: Note that _file timestamp_ more commonly refers to the _last modification time_ of the file (`stat -c%Y` with GNU `stat`) as opposed to the _last status change time_ (`%Z`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have GNU find, you can do it entirely using `find`:

```
find / -printf '%p %C@\n'
```

[The format specifiers are:](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html)

> ```
>      %p     File's name.
>      %Ck    File's last status change time in the format specified by
>             k, which is the same as for %A.
>      %Ak    File's last access time in the  format  specified  by  k,
>             which  is  either `@' or a directive for the C `strftime'
>             function.  The possible values for k  are  listed  below;
>             some  of  them might not be available on all systems, due
>              to differences in `strftime' between systems.
>
>              @      seconds  since  Jan.  1,  1970,  00:00  GMT,  with
>                     fractional part.
> ```

If you don't want fractional parts, use `s` instead of `@` as the time format specifier. (There are a few systems without `s`, but Linux and *BSD/OSX do have `s`.)

```
find / -printf '%p %Cs\n'
```

Comment: It's likely he has GNU `find`. His `stat` could have been GNU or `busybox` `stat`, but since `busybox` `xargs` doesn't have `-L`, it's likely he's on a GNU system.

Comment: For me, this is not entirely the answer. For me it outputs

    /path/to/file 1501831518.9714507480.

I found a solution to my problem and will post an answer.

Comment: @Gamer1120 so strip the fractional part of the timestamp with `sed`.  that's still going to be much faster than forking `stat` many thousands of times.    e.g. `find / -printf '%p %C@\n' | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//'`

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try.

Comment: @Gamer1120 Use `s` instead of `@` if you don't want the fractional part.

Comment: @Gilles where is that documented? I could swear I pored over [the find manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time-Components) but didn't see any format specifier which omitted the fractional part. Is every format specifier valid for [`strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html) also valid here?

Comment: @muru The man page states “*k*, which is either `@` or a directive for the  C  `strftime` function.” This information is missing from the full manual. I'll let you write the bug report. Find can either use its own `strftime` or call the one on the platform, I don't know how it picks. The built-in one supports `s`, as do glibc and *BSD.

Answer (score 4):

why don't you ask `find` to `stat` for you ?

```
find / -exec stat -c'%n %Z' {} +
```

find will run stat of every entry (file or directory).

Comment: Yup, that works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using

```
find / | while read filename
    do
    echo -n "$filename " && stat -c%Z $filename
done
```

but I won't use this solution, as Archemar's answer looks nicer.

Comment: to be honest muru's solution is even finer as `find` won't fork `stat`, so it should be faster as well (now there is fractionnal part in time ...)

Comment: But I don't get the desired output :( See my answer on their solution.